# How can I register a context menu for a scroll view?

Tags: android

I have an android loyout like this:

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/scrollview">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </ScrollView>
```

How can I register a context menu so that it will pop up when user long press anywhere in the scroll view?

I have tried find the scrollview and and register context menu for that:

```
ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
registerForContextMenu(scrollView);
```

But that does not, I don't see any context menu pops up. The only way works is if I register my text view for context menu.

But that may cause bad experience since my text view sometimes can be short (1-2 lines/1-2 words) and sometimes it can be long (mult sentences).

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: depending on what you want in the menu it may work to just get a reference to your ScrollView and set a LongClickListener on it. Then in the callback for that you could inflate and show the dialog yourself. Probably not ideal but I think it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas:

Set the scrollview to be long clickable (might be false by default, not sure)

```
scrollView.setLongClickable(true);
```

If that doesn't work, set your own OnLongClickListener, and from within it, manually call ScrollView's showContextMenu method.