# ContextMenu in ListFragment ignoring longPress because of HorizontalScrollView. How to solve?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-listfragment, android-scrollview

I am working on an XML design file for an Android application and got an issue with my ListFragment (android.support.v4.app.ListFragment).

The problem:
If I add HorizontalScrollView to my XML layout (to put my TextView inside) the ContextMenu (android.view.ContextMenu) wont open by long press on one item in the list.

When I delete the HorizontalScrollViews everything works fine. That means just placing the TextView without the HorizontalScrollView.

The Log gives no error or warning. The problem should be from the XML not within the Java Code.

```
<!-- main root-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<!-- SOME MORE STUFF .... -->

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_activity_date">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_short_text_black_18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="type"
        android:id="@+id/tv_activity_type"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- SOME MORE STUFF .... -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, it may be blocking the view somehow. Did someone found a solution for that? Thanks in advance ! : )

**Edit:**
I tried putting the HorizontalScrollView in the root View and placing nothing into it, also defining no size. So its just a part of the whole layout, but with no useage. Even now, the HorizontalScrollView blocks the ListFragment items, so i cant long touch/press to open the ContextMenu. If I delete it, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDITED

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592747/horizontal-scroll-view-detect-long-press) is the correct answer, and works fine.

Add this code in your `OnCreate()` or `OnCreateView()`

```
 final HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontal);

    registerForContextMenu(horizontalScrollView);

    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
        {
            openContextMenu(horizontalScrollView);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, listener);

    horizontalScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

1-Are you setting the correct view in `registerforContextMenu()`?

2-If your TextView (after long press) opens context menu, maybe need to `setLongClickable()` your `HorizontalScrollView`. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104341/how-can-i-register-a-context-menu-for-a-scroll-view)

3-You really need `HorizontalScrollView` with `TextView`? Look this [HorizontalScrollView references](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: 1 - I do, 2 - does not work, 3 - The HorizontalScrollView ist the only way my view worked, except the ContextMenu. The way with defining maxLines didnt work yet, but I may try it again.